# Spark: Single pipelined scala command better than separate commands?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark with scala. I wanted to know if having single one line command better than separate commands? What are the benefits if any? Does it gain more efficiency in terms of speed? Why?

for e.g.

```
var d = data.filter(_(1)==user).map(f => (f(2),f(5).toInt)).groupByKey().map(f=> (f._1,f._2.count(x=>true), f._2.sum))
```

against

```
var a = data.filter(_(1)==user)
var b = a.map(f => (f(2),f(5).toInt))
var c = b.groupByKey()
var d = c.map(f=> (f._1,f._2.count(x=>true), f._2.sum))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no performance difference between your two examples; the decision to chain RDD transformations or to explicitly represent the intermediate RDDs is just a matter of style.  Spark's lazy evaluation means that no actual distributed computation will be performed until you invoke an RDD action like `take()` or `count()`.

During execution, Spark will pipeline as many transformations as possible.  For your example, Spark won't materialize the entire filtered dataset before it maps it: the `filter()` and `map()` transformations will be pipelined together and executed in a single stage.  The `groupByKey()` transformation (usually) needs to shuffle data over the network, so it's executed in a separate stage.  Spark would materialize the output of `filter()` only if it had been `cache()`d.

You might need to use the second style if you want to cache an intermediate RDD and perform further processing on it.  For example, if I wanted to perform multiple actions on the output of the `groupByKey()` transformation, I would write something like

```
val grouped = data.filter(_(1)==user)
                  .map(f => (f(2),f(5).toInt))
                  .groupByKey()
                  .cache()
val mapped = grouped.map(f=> (f._1,f._2.count(x=>true), f._2.sum))
val counted = grouped.count()
```

Comment: The part where you explain materialization (para-2) is little confusing. Can you refer me any readings on it? Thx

Comment: @Vijay: I meant to clarify how/when Spark decides to pipeline operations.  A non-pipelined version of your code would first filter the entire dataset, then map each filtered record, then group the records by key, etc.  Between the time that it filters the records and maps them, the framework would need to materialize the filtered records to input them into the map phase.  Spark will pipeline the filter and map operations because your code doesn't contain any operations that need to access the filtered (but not mapped) records directly, but adding filter(..).cache() will break that pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in terms of execution, but you might want to consider the readability of your code. I would go with your first example but like this:

```
var d = data.filter(_(1)==user)
.map(f => (f(2),f(5).toInt))
.groupByKey()
.map(f=> (f._1,f._2.count(x=>true), f._2.sum))
```

Really this is more of a Scala question than Spark though. Still, as you can see from Spark's implementation of word count as shown in their [documentation](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/examples.html)

```
val file = spark.textFile("hdfs://...")
val counts = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                 .map(word => (word, 1))
                 .reduceByKey(_ + _)
counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...")
```

you don't need to worry about those kinds of things. The Scala language (through laziness, etc.) and Spark's RDD implementation handles all that at a higher level of abstraction.

If you find really bad performance, then you should take the time to explore why. As [Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) said, "premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer but my question really relates to the intermediate RDD which are created viz. a,b,c in the second example. Are such temporary RDD also created in pipelined commands?

Comment: I clarified in my answer, which might help.